# Keep basic information about each module in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb

I'm design my own application for study graduate and i face with problem on database level. If i may i would like to ask for an advice / suggestion.

In my system every record in the system need to keep few basics information like:
- creator 
- current owner 
- created time 
- status record (moved to trash or not) 
etc

For example i need same basic data above for: 
* Users 
* Files ( Which will be shared between users ) 
* Notificaitons ( for User ) 
* Employees ( because not every employee is user but every employee keep data like creation time ) 
etc

So i thought the good idea would be keep all of that data in one table and reference it to other tables of modules.

And that's the core of my problem. How can i design and implement this concatenation. I tried look for tables in schema (i'm using MariaDB ) and list them in one table but it won't convince me.

Maybe you heared or read about some solutions for that kind problem.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

`Users` and `Files` are 1-to-many, correct?  Then you 'must' use two different tables.  (Etc.)

The fact that created/owner/time/status are in every table is not a violation of database design principles.

A thought is to put those for columns in another table.  But they are essentially independent of each other, so that does not make sense.

Back to the general concept of tables.  Ponder what "Entities" you have (users, files, notifications, employees).  Then think about how they are related in this way:

- 1:1 -- Put info in a single table
- 1:many -- two tables; the "many" table has the `id` of the "one".
- many:many -- 3 tables; the extra one is the mapping between the other two; it has an `id` to each other table, and usually no other columns.

After that, you can get to work populating the tables -- id, name, created_time, status, etc.